# PyTorch LSTM with multivariate time series (Many-to-Many)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Given 5 features on a time series we want to predict the following values using an LSTM Recurrent Neural Network, using PyTorch. The problem is that the Loss Value starts very low (i.e. 0.04) and it increases a bit as the computation runs (it seems it converge to a slightly higher value, but it never decreases).

Moreover, the dataset is normalized, and we tried different values of learning rate, epochs, batch sizes etc.
An example of loss during training:

```
step :  0 loss :  0.0016425768844783306
step :  1 loss :  0.0028163508977741003
step :  2 loss :  0.009786984883248806
```

This is the class:

```
class MV_LSTM(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self,n_features,seq_length):
    super(MV_LSTM, self).__init__()
    self.n_features = n_features
    self.seq_len = seq_length
    self.n_hidden = 40 # number of hidden states
    self.n_layers = 1 # number of LSTM layers (stacked)

    self.l_lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size = n_features, 
                             hidden_size = self.n_hidden,
                             num_layers = self.n_layers, 
                             batch_first = True)
    # according to pytorch docs LSTM output is 
    # (batch_size,seq_len, num_directions * hidden_size)
    # when considering batch_first = True
    self.l_linear = torch.nn.Linear(self.n_hidden*self.seq_len, 5)
    

def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
    hidden_state = torch.randn(self.n_layers,batch_size,self.n_hidden)
    cell_state = torch.randn(self.n_layers,batch_size,self.n_hidden)
    self.hidden = (hidden_state, cell_state)


def forward(self, x):        
    batch_size, seq_len, _ = x.size()
    
    lstm_out, self.hidden = self.l_lstm(x,self.hidden)
   
    x = lstm_out.contiguous().view(batch_size,-1)
    return self.l_linear(x)
```

This is the main code:

```
n_features = 5 # this is number of parallel inputs
n_timesteps = 24 # this is number of timesteps

# convert dataset into input/output
X, y = split_sequences(dataset, n_timesteps)
print(X.shape, y.shape)
X
y

# create NN
mv_net = MV_LSTM(n_features,n_timesteps)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss() # reduction='sum' created huge loss value
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(mv_net.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

train_episodes = 50
batch_size = 16
```

This is the training:

```
mv_net.train()

for t in range(train_episodes):
X, y = sklearn.utils.shuffle(X, y)

for b in range(0,len(X),batch_size):
    inpt = X[b:b+batch_size,:,:]
    target = y[b:b+batch_size,:]    

    
    x_batch = torch.tensor(inpt,dtype=torch.float32)    
    y_batch = torch.tensor(target,dtype=torch.float32)

    mv_net.init_hidden(x_batch.size(0))

    output = mv_net(x_batch) 
    loss = criterion(output.view(-1,5), y_batch) 
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()        
    optimizer.zero_grad() 
print('step : ' , t , 'loss : ' , loss.item())
```

Thank you for your time, and sorry for our unexperience (this is our first RNN).